# How can I access attributes inside a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a piece of code that looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var modelJSON = {"id":12345}
```

I am trying to use the Chrome Dev Tools to access the modelJSON variable and the information inside it, but every time I search for modelJSON in the console, it returns "VM6586:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: modelJSON is not defined at :1:1"

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the line right after the one defining `modelJSON`. While it is stopped there in the same scope you should be able to access it.

Comment: Try `console.log(modelJSON)` on the line below `var modelJSON = {"id":12345}` and check the console ... if it doesn't work please edit your question and add the full code.

Comment: `modelJSON` is defined in a function closure, to be able to access it using devtools, you need to either define it outside of the function or do `window.modelJSON = {"id":12345}`

Comment: Add `debugger;` after `var modelJSON = {"id": 12345}` to check.